# Django Problema de importacion views

Tags: django, importación

estoy siguiendo un turotial de django tengo un problema al momento con el servidor cuando intento importar views  de la cerpeta de my app. No conosco mucho de django todavia, me podrian ayudar? gracias (este es el error que aparece en el cmd)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\DJANGO_TOMA_133\lojavirtual\Scripts\LOJA\LOJA\urls.py", line 18, in 
from shop import views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shop'

Esto es lo que habia cambiado:

en views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Products
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    product_objects = Products.objects.all()
    return render (render,'shop/index.html', {'product_objects': product_objects})
```

y en urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from shop import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',view.index,name='index')
]
```

gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes compartir la estructura de tu proyecto por favor.

Lo que te puedo aportar es que verifiques que tengas el archivo **init**.py, este puede ir vacío y este debe ir dentro de tu aplicación shop, donde tienes tu views.py

Lo siguiente es que verifiques que tu aplicación este incluida en tu settings en:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
)
```

Answer (score 0):

me parece que el problema lo tenes en urls.py

```
from shop import views
```

cuando lo que tenes que hacer es

```
from views import index
```

Comment: from views import index me ecaba de salvar. Gracias